# when i run android studio on ubuntu 14.04 i get this

Tags: java

```
AAPT err(1192846461): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1576436088): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(324591639): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1664954357): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1445787437): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(868435671): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1299699580): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1711804903): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(889966173): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(2008388571): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(114638052): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(217734523): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(2079642304): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1326520474): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(571987854): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1801867011): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(333027892): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(4377110): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(569565757): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1270177687): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_15" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_13" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_16" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_9" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_14" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider formatting your question and code. Refer [ask].

Comment: Well, as the old joke goes, "stop doing it then" !

Comment: alex am serious so stop those jokes

Comment: Cuuld you possibly post a more detailed error dump?

Comment: AAPT err(1192846461): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1576436088): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(324591639): /opt/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved same problem on my PC with Ubuntu 15.10 64bit with installation 32bit version of **libz** package.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Answer (score 1):

After formatting, the problem (or at least the first problem) becomes fairly obvious: you're apparently missing `libz.so.1` on the target machine (or at least the program in question can't find it). So, your first step is to get that installed. Impossible to guess whether that will fix everything, but it should deal with at least some (and quite possibly all) of what you're seeing.